# Classes that intern in Java

Tags: java, string

Which Java classes are interning?

String is.

The descendants of Number don't seem to be interning.

Are there any others in the java.lang or in APIs that are interning? i.e., bringing an already existing object from the pool when that value of the class is called for multiple times?

Comment: Not in the same sense as `String`, because that is done natively, but some of the `Number` classes do hold a cache of values that they return from their `valueOf()` methods.

Comment: The only class with an architected intern mechanism is String.  The others are more like "caching instances", and, to my knowledge, are not required to exhibit interning behavior.

Comment: (BTW, if you have the literal "Some String" in three different classes, those are *required* to all have the same address such that you can reliably use `==` compares between them.  No other Class makes this guarantee.)

Comment: @HotLicks Some primitives' boxed types do, for certain values.

Comment: @yshavit - Interning "certain values" doesn't really guarantee anything.

Comment: @HotLicks If one class writes `Integer a = 123`, and another class writes `Integer b = 123`, then `a == b` is guaranteed by the JLS (5.1.7). I wouldn't say that does guarantee something. You just have to be a bit more careful with it than you need to be with strings.

Comment: @HotLicks the wrappers are bringing the same instance on assignment to another ref. and are bypassing this look-up-the-pool when i explicitly call their constructors for a value. this is what String is doing ,so they behave the same looking at it from "outside". must beb some difference in keeping the value pools internally.

Comment: @yshavit - I believe it's 5.1.8.  And the effect is as if the operands were unboxed.

Comment: @Roam You are correct. It looks the same from the outside. Internally,  when you have `Integer a = 12`, the compiler actually produces the following code: `Integer a = Interger.valueOf(12);`. And `valueOf(int)` will check the `Integer` cache. For `String`, it's a little different. For `String s = "123";`, the compiler will keep a special reference to the literal `"123"`. The byte code to assign the value `"123"` to `s` will use that reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the wrapper classes have an internal cache mechanism.  They cache values that range from -128 to 127.

A couple of special cases to note:

- `Character` is special in that, since a `char` < 0 has no meaning, it caches from 0 to 128.
- `Boolean` creates static constants of true and false, so it is always a cached wrapper.

Admittedly this isn't in the same sense as a `String` (since that's VM interning as opposed to runtime), but there does exist some small bit of caching for those wrapper classes.